# Convert sql output to following format

Tags: sql

I want to convert sql out put to following format.
Here is my table.

```
Id  Country Code    Totalcount
1   India   20      120
2   India   21      121
3   India   22      122
4   India   23      123
5   India   24      124
6   US      20      220
7   US      21      221
8   Us      22      222
9   UK      23      323
10  UK      24      324

Select Country, 20,21,22,23,24,25
from
(
   Select Country,StatusCode,Totalcount from StatusDetails
) as SourceTable
Pivot
(
 sum(Totalcount) for StatusCode in (20,21,22,23,24,25)
) as PivotTable
```

In Need Output like below one.Do I need to apply pivot table.

```
Country 20  21  22  23  24
India   120 121 122 123 124
US      220 221 222     
UK                  323 324
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a fan of conditional aggregation for this purpose:

```
select country,
       max(case when code = 20 then totalcount end) as cnt_20,
       max(case when code = 21 then totalcount end) as cnt_21,
       max(case when code = 22 then totalcount end) as cnt_22,
       max(case when code = 23 then totalcount end) as cnt_23,
       max(case when code = 24 then totalcount end) as cnt_24
from sourcetable
group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need pivot & your code would also work along with quote's :

```
select pt.*
from (select Country, Code, Totalcount 
      from sourcetable
     )as SourceTable Pivot
     (sum(Totalcount) for Code in ([20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25])
     )as pt;
```